# API is not appearing in the Network Tab's XHR section to scrape all the data listed on the site

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, browser, automation, single-page-application

Maybe I am dealing with a `Single Page Application` I am not an expert cannot tell, what I know for sure is upon inspecting `Network` tab's `XHR` section I used to get link to call the API to get data for the items listed on the site. I am trying to do the same with this site **check here** -
**https://all-spares.com/en/** but the API does not seem to appear.

Here is a screenshot from one of the product's detail page -

[image]

I have tried the same method on homepage also but that also does not show any relevant info, and also **the data shown in the screenshot is incomplete and does not match to that product's attributes** so in case you think I missed that!

In general I want to know is there no way to get API endpoint that renders data to the front end, and if so then how can I get data for sites like these.

Any help is highly appriciated, I tried to keep it as open as possible, its a simple scrapping issue otherwise I would have to scrape the whole site for each product with `Selenium` by extracting data from the HTML, that would be a nightmare!